# sql split string based on delimiter with varying numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I split this string `10.159.101.0-10.159.101.255` into two strings?

I can accomplish this in Mysql in this manner:

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('10.159.101.0-10.159.101.255','-',1)as string1
```

How can I accomplish the same thing in SQL?  I'd like to split the IP range into two strings based on the `-` delimiter which can vary in position due to the nature of IP addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a combination of `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX` & `LEN`.

```
SELECT yourfield,
SUBSTRING(yourfield, 1,CHARINDEX('-', yourfield)-1) LEFTSIDE,
SUBSTRING(yourfield, CHARINDEX('-', yourfield)+1, LEN(yourfield)) RIGHTSIDE
FROM yourtable
```

Output

```
yourfield                   LEFTSIDE      RIGHTSIDE
10.159.101.0-10.159.101.255 10.159.101.0  10.159.101.255
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb36f/3/0

Comment: You where too fast for me, I had to re-write my answer :-) +1.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you would use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` as demonstrated in Matt's answer, or `LEFT` and `RIGHT` like this:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(50);
SET @string = '10.159.101.0-10.159.101.255';
SELECT LEFT(@string, CHARINDEX('-', @string)-1) As First,
       RIGHT(@string, LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX('-', @string)) As Second
```